# visual studio code extension capability

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to develop an extension for VSC that user can draw in the editor area. In the extension, the user should be able to select a shape in the explorer area and drag and drop it to the editor area and also grad and move an item in the editor area.

I read VSC extension documentation and could not find any information that shows me if the above scenario is possible.

Is it possible to do this:

1- Select an item in the explorer area and drag and drop it to the editor area.

2- Select an item in the editor area and drop it somewhere else (so effectively move the item)

If yes, where can I find samples or more information? which API to use?

Comment: If you can implement it in HTML/JavaScript you can write an extension using a WebView, read on custom editors for VSC

Comment: @rioV8 thanks. That is for question 2, what about question one? the explorer has (where the frees exist) fix format,

Comment: it is the answer for both questions, implement your editor functionality in HTML/JS, or do something like gmail, program in Java and compile to JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a similar extension hediet.vscode-drawio. You can explore its source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/hediet/vscode-drawio)